# wordpress get_results($sql, ARRAY_A) query comments has duplicate comment

Tags: sql, wordpress

When using `get_results($sql, ARRAY_A)` to query wp_comments, there is a comment in the result.

The sql is below

```
SELECT comment_ID,comment_parent,comment_author,comment_author_url,comment_author_email,comment_content,comment_date,comment_type,ck_rating_up,ck_rating_down 
FROM $wpdb->comments 
LEFT JOIN $comment_rating_table 
ON ($wpdb->comments.comment_ID = $comment_rating_table.ck_comment_id) 
WHERE comment_post_ID = $post_id AND comment_approved = 1 
order by comment_id ASC
```

How to avoid duplicate comments?

Comment: @swapnesh: That is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question being asked is, how to get the results containing no duplicates. Since nothing was mentioned as to which field, I will assume it's the main comments field which is of type text, which means you can't use DISTINCT on it.

However since this field contains comments and not novels worth of text, then really there should be no reason for a comment field to be of type text at all. So what needs to happen is for the field to be convert from type text to type varchar, and use (max) as the field size.

The varchar(max) field can hold 64k of data, which is about 10,000-20,000 words depending on the alphabet used. This should be more than enough room to hold a 40 page essay or a single comment.

As for the SQL:

```
 SELECT comment_ID,comment_parent,comment_author,comment_author_url,comment_author_email,comment_content,comment_date,comment_type,ck_rating_up,ck_rating_down 
    FROM $wpdb->comments 
    LEFT JOIN $comment_rating_table 
    ON ($wpdb->comments.comment_ID = $comment_rating_table.ck_comment_id) 
    WHERE comment_post_ID = $post_id
    AND comment_approved = 1
    AND comment_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT( comment_content ) FROM $wpdb->comments 
    LEFT JOIN $comment_rating_table 
    ON ($wpdb->comments.comment_ID = $comment_rating_table.ck_comment_id) 
    WHERE comment_post_ID = $post_id AND comment_approved = 1)
    order by comment_id ASC
```

A faster option is instead of DISTINCT to use GROUP BY comment_content , and then selecting either the MIN or MAX

```
  SELECT comment_ID,comment_parent,comment_author,comment_author_url,comment_author_email,comment_content,comment_date,comment_type,ck_rating_up,ck_rating_down 
    FROM $wpdb->comments 
    LEFT JOIN $comment_rating_table(
    SELECT MAX(comment_id) AS id FROM comment GROUP BY comment_content
   maxid ON ($wpdb->comments.comment_ID = $comment_rating_table.ck_comment_id)  WHERE comment_post_ID = $post_id AND comment_approved = 1) order by comment_id ASC
```